# How do I add a role to a user with a discord bot in java if I have their ID as a String?

Tags: java, bots, discord

I want to add a role to a user in discord based on who was mentioned in a message. I've been looking and looking but am unable to find anything about adding a role to a user when i have their id as a string. To get the id of the person that is mentioned I use the line

```
String name = event.getMember().getUser().getAsMention();
```

But I am unsure of how to actually add the role to the person after I get their name/id. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the author's ID **as a long value** in order to get it as a member instance

```
long authorID = event.getMessage().getAuthor().getIdLong();
Member member = event.getGuild().getMemberById(authorID);
Role role = event.getMessage().getMentionedRoles().get(0); //checks for mentioned roles in the message

      event
            .getGuild()
            .getController()
            .addSingleRoleToMember(member, role)
            .complete();
```

The above code adds a single role to the member by accessing the guild's controller. A `.addRolesToMember()` method exists, but to add multiple roles, you would need a variable with the type `Collection<Role>` . Also, make sure to add exception handling as the third line of code may produce an exception if there are no mentioned roles.